# How to fade letter by latter and change the text?

Tags: jquery

I would like to show a text example: Hello world! and then 2 seconds later start fade out letter by letter and then change something different string and fadein letter by letter also?

***UPDATE***

I tried this one:

```
$(function () {
  var string = "Hello World!",
      stringCount = 0;
 stringCount=0;
  setInterval(function(){
    $('#fade').append(string[stringCount]);
    stringCount += 1;
  },1000);    

});
```

It is do the fade in letter by letter, and after show the whole string i would like to beginning the fade out, after fade out i want to change the string and again also fade in and out... but yet i dont know how to do that...

Comment: And what have you tried so far to do this yourself, SO is not a coding service

Comment: i updated the code hwat i trying